# EmguCV bug using StereoBM class AccessViolationException

Tags: opencv, access-violation, emgucv

Hi i tried compute disparity map using EmguCV, but there must be some bug when i try use StereoBM class, always when i call function FindStereoCorrespondence i will receive this error:

System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory.

My code is simple:

```
    private Image<Gray, byte> Computer3DPointsFromStereoPair0(Image<Gray, byte> left, Image<Gray, byte> right)
    {
        Size size = left.Size;
        Image<Gray, short> disparityMap = new Image<Gray, short>(size);
        using (StereoBM stereoSolver = new StereoBM(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.STEREO_BM_TYPE.BASIC, 0)){
            stereoSolver.FindStereoCorrespondence(left, right, disparityMap);
        } 
        return disparityMap.Convert<Gray, byte>();

    }
```

I think it can be somewere in OpenCV dll's...

Please if somebody know how to slove that problem!

Comment: +1 for this question, as I've run into the same issue. Emgu CV version 2.9.0.1922